# Find and crop largest interior bounding box of image

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-graphics, core-image

I made an optical hardware that I can get stereo images from and I'm developing a helper application for this hardware. With this equipment, I shoot an object from 3 different angles. I fold the photo into 3 different image variables. This is what photos become when I correct distortions caused by perspective with CIPerspectiveTransform. There are redundant areas you see in the images and I do not use these areas.

Perspective corrected image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK7tK.gif

I focus the images by dragging and after focusing I try to get the intersection areas. I can get the intersection areas of 3 images of different sizes and shapes with the CISourceInCompositing filter. However, the resulting images appear in irregular formats. Due to the proportional processes I use in focusing, images also contain transparent areas. You can download and test this image. https://i.imgur.com/uo8Srvv.png

Composited image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/22phZ.png
Composited animated image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovAoS.gif

```
func intersectImages(inputImage: UIImage, backgroundImage:UIImage) -> UIImage {
        
        if let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceInCompositing") {
            
            let inputImageCi = CIImage.init(image: inputImage)
            let backgroundImageCi = CIImage.init(image: backgroundImage)
            
            currentFilter.setValue(inputImageCi,forKey: "inputImage")
            currentFilter.setValue(backgroundImageCi,forKey:"inputBackgroundImage")
            
            let context = CIContext.init()
            
            if let outputImage = currentFilter.outputImage {
                if let extent = backgroundImageCi?.extent {
                    if let cgOutputImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: extent){
                        return UIImage.init(cgImage: cgOutputImage)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return UIImage.init()
    }
```

The problem I'm stuck with is: Is it possible to extract the images as rectangles while first getting these intersection areas or after the intersection operations? I couldn't come up with any solution. I'm trying to get the green framed photo I shared as a final.

Target image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbSuw.png

Target image animated https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gQa6.gif

Comment: Google search for `find largest rectangle in polygon` is probably a good place to start.

Comment: It's not a trivial problem. I recommend this blog post, it may give you some insights: https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for suggest. I find some solution on other languages, but i can't convert swift.

Comment: @de. Thanks you for link. If i find that on swift language solution it could be great.

Comment: Where do you get points for the `CIPerspectiveTransform` from? You might be able to infer the inner bounding box based on those points.

Comment: @Vileriu - well, it's going to be mostly math, which is no different between languages. If your research has found what looks like a good solution, start working on it. If you run into specific coding problems, ask specific questions.

Comment: The algorithm is just a bit over 100 lines. I reads very well. Shouldn’t be too hard.

Comment: @FrankRupprecht Hi. i found largest area with your suggest. Thanks you so much Frank.

Comment: @Vileriu Glad I could help.  Please consider posting the solution by answering your own question. Others might benefit from it. Thanks!